# How do I use Google Analytics _trackEvent on a clickable Flash banner?

Tags: javascript, flash, google-analytics, actionscript-2, event-tracking

Currently, I use the following href tags around my jpg banners to track whenever someone clicks on them:

`<a href="#" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Banner Ads','Zwanger Pesiri', 'Skyscraper']);" target="_blank"></a>`

I now have a Flash ad that I need to use in the same manner, but I'm not that good with either Actionscript or Javascript. My Flash banner has the following Actionscript to make the ad clickable:

```
on(release) {
getURL("http://www.zwangerpesiri.com", "_blank");
}
```

How do I change the Actionscript so that it has the tracking info attached to it that the jpg would have?

Comment: Just an update... The following almost works:
 on(release){

getURL("javascript:javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Banner Ads', 'Zwanger Pesiri', 'Skyscraper']);");
getURL("http://www.zwangerpesiri.com","_blank");

}

The problem is that the page that holds the ad changes and just shows 0 on the page after the ad is clicked... Anybody know how I can correct that?

Comment: Another update.... The following works almost the way I want it to, except that in Firefox it will cause the link to open in both the source window and new window:
on(release){
getURL("javascript:javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Banner Ads', 'Zwanger Pesiri', 'Skyscraper']); void(0);");
getURL("http://www.zwangerpesiri.com","_blank");
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this ActionScript in your `on(release)` event:

```
ExternalInterface.call("_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','Banner Ads', 'Zwanger Pesiri', 'Skyscraper'])");
```

This assumes you already have the Google Analytics on your site somewhere. Otherwise, you'd need to include the AnalyticsTracker and GATracker libraries in your Flash file (which also significantly increases the .swf file size).

[Here is an example I made](https://gearside.com/nebula/documentation/custom-functionality/flash-banner-analytics/) where you can download my .fla files if you're interested in learning more.